# Why do they want to replace Godzilla instead of killing it?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-vs-kong

Madison encountered Mechangodzilla at the  Apex facility and says to Bernie:

> Madison: This is why Godzilla attacked the Apex facility. They're trying
> to **replace him**.

Why do they want to replace Godzilla instead of killing it?

Comment: because they wanted a mecha-lizard they control rather than a wild overgrown salamander that destroys anything whenever it feels like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simmons' plan is to systematically kill all of the Titans (using his mecha) and regain humanity's primacy over the Earth. He's also mindful that with this power, he'll essentially be king of the world, but only once he kills Godzilla and has his own super-robot at his disposal.

> “As expected,” Simmons replied. “Don’t worry, once the Hollow Earth
> signal is uploaded, our power troubles will be over.”
>
> “If they can find the energy source,” Ren said. He tried to rein in
> his pessimism, the disappointment. He had been so close! To be shut
> down like that was … hard to take. He needed more power. He craved it.
> Only then could the Mecha be what he had designed it to be. Only then
> could he be what he was meant to be.
>
> “I have faith in Maia,” Simmons replied. “I have faith in our
> creation. **And humanity will once again be the apex species. And once I
> destroy Godzilla, the world will bow to me.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Godzilla Vs. Kong - Official Novelisation](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Kong_-_The_Official_Movie_Novelization)</sup></sub>